# When do I need to use a `New` keyword when creating an array?

Tags: vb.net

I was just looking at the [help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) page for arrays in VB and apparently all of these are acceptable syntax for creating arrays:

```
Dim numbers(4) As Integer 

inquiriesByYearMonthDay = New Byte(20)()() {}

Dim sales()() As Double = New Double(11)() {}
```

Note that the first one doesn't even have a `New` keyword, the second one only has a `New` keyword, and the third one uses both the `Dim` and `New` keywords.  Why is there so much inconsistency and which one are you supposed to use?  I'm most curious about the first one since the array object is never even being created

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming, where are (always) multiple ways to do things. You pick one which suits your style. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, only the first array is created and ready for use.  The others are merely declared as arrays (or partially created).

```
Dim numbers(4) As Integer
Dim sales()() As Double = New Double(11)() {}
```

As Intellisense shows, `numbers` is ready to use. For the jagged array `sales` - an array of arrays- the code has so far just told it how many arrays it will hold.  Each of those is `Nothing` because the code has not created or assigned one to any of the slots:

[image]

The line declaring `sales` is actually doing two things which can be confusing.  It could have been declared like this:

```
' at some point I will want an array of array of doubles named sales:
Dim sales()() As Double

' Ok, I need it to hold 12 double arrays:
sales =  New Double(11)() {}
```

Step one declares the variable and Type.  Step 2 defines the "container array" by creating a temp array and assigning it.  (The link tries to illustrate this with `inquiriesByYearMonthDay` - it is declared in the preceding block.)

Sales still isnt ready to use, it just a bunch of `Nothing`.

```
' Ok, I need the first array to hold 5 elements
sales(0) = New Double(4) {}       ' 0 based, so 4 == 5 items
sales(0)(0) = 12.67               ' FINALLY we can use it
```

Now, `sales(0)(0 thru 4)` can store data.  `sales(1)()` and the rest have not been initialized.

The `New` isnt really acting on `sales` directly.  It is creating a new, temp array (on the right) which is immediately assigned to a slot in `sales()` on the left.

The key is: arrays are ready to use when given a size. So, these are functionally identical:

```
' create int array with 5 slots:
Dim numbers(4) As Integer
' declare array; assign empty 4 slot int array to it:
Dim numbers() As Int32 = New Int32(4) {}
```

The first declaration includes the size; the second assigns a (new) temp array of a specified size to it.  That said, VB can infer the size:

Dim fishes As String() = {"cod", "salmon", "tuna", "perch", "barracuda"}

The `{...}` is another temp array, which VB assigns to 'fishes'.

---

But arrays are just clunky.  What will `sales(6,3)` represent? To make them readable you need constants everywhere: `foo = sales(SALES_MARCH, SALES_ZIGGY)`. Personally, I think the only good array is a static array with known, fixed values:

```
Dim Days As String() = {"sun", "mon", "tues"....}
```

Otherwise, `List(Of T)`, `Dictionary(TK, TV)`, `Collection(Of T)` and many many others are easier to use, create, manage and work with (they size themselves!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are, however you would use new if you say had the array, in a sub routine and wanted it empty your next run trhough. You may also want to look at list of strings