# How would I create a jagged array with the inner array having a varying number of elements?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I'm currently trying to develop my code in Visual Studio using VB.NET and I'm having a confusing issue. I don't think that a two-dimensional array will help here. I'm trying to set up a jagged array. This code,

`Dim rootsOfRangeUL(CInt(Math.Floor(sqrtOfUL) - 1), CInt(Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(Math.Sqrt(upperLimit))) - 1)) As Integer`

returns the output:

```
-       rootsOfRangeUL  
    (0, 0)  0   Integer - Three values each
    (0, 1)  1   Integer
    (0, 2)  1   Integer
    (1, 0)  1   Integer
    (1, 1)  1   Integer
    (1, 2)  1   Integer
    (2, 0)  1   Integer
    (2, 1)  1   Integer
    (2, 2)  1   Integer
```

The current 2D array has 3 fields for the second dimension. However, I want the second dimension of the array to have a varying number of fields. That is,

```
(0, 0)  0 - Two values each
(0, 1)  1
(1, 0)  1
(1, 1)  1
...
(8, 0)  x1 - Three values each
(8, 1)  x2
(8, 2)  x3
...
(n,m_k) x_k - k values each
```

What type of array structure would I need here? (Jagged, Multi-D Jagged?)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of several of the posts listed under **Related**

Comment: also see [When do I need to use a `New` keyword when creating an array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35004563/1070452) which may help (as well as [Arrays on Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/index#a-namebkmkjaggedarraysa-jagged-arrays)

Comment: You could use a "list of lists", as in `List(Of List(Of Integer))`.